# Why is my code not retrieving the data in a graph?

Tags: php, sql-server, graph, while-loop

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include "../../lib/mssql.connect.php";

    $params = array($_POST['year'], sha1($_POST['month']));
    $sql ="SELECT count(*) AS TotalGuestBook_TotalCount, MONTH(GuestBook_CreatedDate) as mth from tbl_Guestbook
           WHERE YEAR(GuestBook_CreatedDate) ='2015'
           group by MONTH(GuestBook_CreatedDate)"; 

    // run the query
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params)

        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $dashboardResult[] = array('label' =>$row['GuestBook_CreatedDate'], 'values' =>$row['TotalGuestBook_TotalCount']);
        }
    echo json_encode($dashboardResult);
?>
```

Comment: sorry the error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in 17

Comment: you didnt accept any answer yet after getting solution on other question aswell.........

Answer (score 0):

Do not include `$params` in query execution
Use:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

instead of :

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params)
```

Comment: still getting the same error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in 17

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its a parse error you missed the termination semi colon in this line:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params)
```

This should be:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
```

---

For **undefined index error**, you are using wrong column names:

```
$dashboardResult[] = array('label' =>$row['GuestBook_CreatedDate'], 'values' =>$row['TotalGuestBook_TotalCount']);
```

Should be:

```
$dashboardResult[] = array('label' =>$row['mth'], 'values' =>$row['TotalGuestBook_TotalCount']);
```

You are defining the index name as `$row['GuestBook_CreatedDate']` but in query you are using alias for this field as `mth`.

Comment: now the error is Undefined index: GuestBook_CreatedDate. why is this so?

Comment: because this should be $row['mth'] @stewart